# Make and c++ files, "includes" in the cpp

Tags: c++, makefile

This is my current makefile:

```
# Compiler #
CXX      = g++
DEBUG    = -g
LFLAGS   =
CXXFLAGS = -Wall

# Directories #
SRCDIR   = src/
INCDIR   = include/
BUILDDIR = build/
BINDIR   = bin/

# Objects #
OBJ_NAMES = main.o dfa.o dfaException.o state.o
OBJS       = $(addprefix $(BUILDDIR), $(OBJ_NAMES))

# Output #
NAME = pract3
TARGET = $(BINDIR)pract3

# Clean #
ifeq ($(OS),Windows_NT)
    RM = del /q /s $(BUILDDIR:/=\)*.o $(BINDIR:/=\)$(NAME)*
else
    RM = rm -rf $(BUILDDIR)*.o $(TARGET)*
endif

# Files #
$(TARGET): $(OBJS)
    $(CXX) $(CXXFLAGS) $(LFLAGS) $(OBJS) -o $(TARGET)

$(BUILDDIR)%.o: $(SRCDIR)%.cpp
    $(CXX) $(CXXFLAGS) $(LFLAGS) -c $< -o $@

clean:
    $(RM)
```

And this is my project tree:

```
Porject/

    bin/

    build/

    doc/
        ...

    include/
        connection.hpp
        dfa.hpp
        dfaException.hpp
        state.hpp

    src/
        dfa.cpp
        dfaException.cpp
        main.cpp
        state.cpp

    Makefile
    Readme
```

Now, I'm having three "problems".

First I want my makefile to create the bin and build directories just in case they aren't. I guess I just have to use:

```
mkdir $(BUILDDIR)
mkdir $(BINDIR)
```

But where should I put them ? And also, how can I prevent mkdir and rm (or del in windows) messages like "Cant find ..." or "x directory already exists ... "

Second, I'm guessing I can read the objects name from src/ (converting the .cpp to .o), but how can I read the file names from a directory ?

Last, I have one template class: `connection.hpp` (all functions are in the header). This file is included in `state.hpp` using: `#include "../include/connection.hpp"`. I ran `make` one time with all correct and then I purposely make a syntax error in `connection.hpp`. Then I ran `make` again, but It only compiled the target file using the `.o` files in build without any error. Everytime I want to edit `connection.hpp` I have to use `make clean` and then `make`. Is there any better way to do this ?

Answer (score 1):

1. If you need a directory to exist before you can proceed, simply put

   ```
   mkdir -p ${DIRECTORY}
   ```

   before you need it in your rule.  If the directory already exists, `mkdir -p` will happily do nothing.

   Likewise, if you use `rm -f FILE`, it should not complain if `FILE` does not exist in the first place.
2. There is no portable way to create a variable that holds the names of all files in a directory.  But you are already using GNU Make features anyway, so you can just use

   ```
   SOURCES = $(wildcard ${SRCDIR}/*.cpp)
   ```

   and then

   ```
   OBJECTS = $(SOURCES:.cpp=.o)
   ```

   to transform them into object file names.  You'll probably want to replace the leading directory name as well, I guess.
3. You didn't list any `*.hpp` files as prerequisites in your make file. You can either manually add them like

   ```
   foo.o: foo.cpp bar.hpp baz.hpp
   ```

   but that becomes unpleasant very quickly.  Another trick is to use the compiler to tell you the headers (transitively) `#include`d by a file.  If you are using GCC, you can run

   ```
   gcc -MM foo.cpp
   ```

   to have it output above make-file snippet.  You can put a pattern rule like the following

   ```
   %.deps: %.cpp
       ${CXX} -MM ${CPPFLAGS} $< > $@
   ```

   into your make-file and then `include` the generated `*.deps` files.

   ```
   include $(SOURCES:.cpp=.deps)
   ```

   GNU Make will be smart enough to first parse the make-file, recognize that the `*.deps` files don't exist and therefore cannot be `include`d but figure out that there is a rule to generate them.  So it will execute that rule and then continue parsing the make-file.

   I have learned that trick from Peter Miller's great article [*Recursive Make Considered Harmful*](http://lcgapp.cern.ch/project/architecture/recursive_make.pdf) which is a good read if you want to learn how to write good make-files.

Comment: This information turned very useful to me, thanks, but I cant manage to get the last part to work. Where should the include go ?. Im using it like: `DEPS=$(OBJS:.o=.deps)`  and then, before all the recipes Im doing `include $(DEPS)`. Without the include, the `.deps` files are generated and then erased, but with it, they stay there. Moreover, using the include have no difference, If I compile and then edit `connecion.hpp` there is still no error until I clean and compile all again.

Comment: @Ediolot It is okay for the `*.deps` files to be not deleted. If you want to clean them up, do `rm - f ${DEPS}` in your `clean` target. I cannot reason about why your files don't get compiled as you expect. If you cannot get it working, maybe ask another question with a minimal `Makefile` and some “hello world” program that `#include`s a header that reproduces your problem. Maybe there is a tiny mistake. I can assure you that I'm using this technique a lot and it does work very well.